# namedtuple TypeError count of positional arguments

Tags: python, namedtuple

Why does the TypeError message indicate 3 positional arguments if the namedtuple only calls for two?  Why does it say that 4 were given?

```
from collections import namedtuple
Transition = namedtuple('Transition', ('one', 'two'))
a = Transition(1,2,3)
#TypeError: __new__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: When you call `SomeClass(x, y, z)`, this is sort-of internally translated to `SomeClass.__new__(SomeClass, x, y, z)`. The class is added as an argument (because it may be needed by subclasses in some cases), so the count is one off from what you provide.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument on an instance method is always the instance itself (usually named `self`. Calling `Transition(1,2)` is `Transition.__new__(self, 1, 2)`.

*Edit: thanks @Slam for pointing out that namedtuple used `__new__` instead of `__init__`

Comment: Almost right, but specifically for `namedtuple` it's question of `__new__`, not `__init__` because of underlying implementation.

Comment: if there are 4 arguments (1,2,3,4), its reports 

       TypeError: __new__() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given

And if only 1 argument is given (1), it reports that it is missing 1 required positional argument, not 2

Answer (score 1):

**Reproduce your mistakes**

```
import collections

# Two-way construct numedtuple
# 1st way：use iterable object as 2nd paras
Transition01 = collections.namedtuple('Transition', ['one', 'two'])
# 2nd way：use space-splited string as 2nd paras
Transition02 = collections.namedtuple('Transition', 'one two')

# In order to figure out the field names contained in a namedtuple object, it is recommended to use the _fields attribute.
print(Transition01._fields)
print(Transition01._fields == Transition02._fields)

# After you know the field name contained in a namedtuple object, it is recommended to initialize the namedtuple using keyword arguments because it is easier to debug than positional parameters.
nttmp01 = Transition01(one=1, two=2)
nttmp02 = Transition01(1, 2)
print(nttmp01)
print(nttmp02)
```

***Debug Info***

## =======================================

```
# Transition01(1, 2, 3)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
# TypeError: __new__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

## ========================================

***Technical details you care about***

```
function namedtuple_Transition.Transition.__new__(_cls, one, two)
```

***Analysis:*** The named tuple class object you created has an internal implementation method **new**, and the engineer who defines the method takes the method caller object as the first parameter of the method, and this is a more common class method definition form.